# Clean viewmodel from memory when their associated pages are removed from backstack - WP8.1

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

In my application there are a few pages say - A, B, C which are associated with their respective ViewModels - VMA, VMB, VMC. When the user reaches page C, I want to remove page B from backstack as well as remove its ViewModel (VMB) from ViewmodelLocator's container.

The result should b A->C

I am new to MVVM light. Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I am able to remove the page from backstack by setting the navigation state of the frame. How to remove the viewmodel reference to prevent memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am keeping track of the flows and removing them from ViewModelLocator. This I am doing on two instances

1) When user navigates back from the current page
2) When user navigates to page B where this page A will be cleared from history. I remove A's viewmodel from ViewModelLocator's container and call its clean up to clear its resources.

I will revisit this in future and try to use updated mvvm light library. IF someone finds a way to do this better, please do suggest.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleIoc provides an **Unregister(TClass instance)** overload, to remove an instance.

You could use that in the page's finalizer, but have to check for side-effects, if the VM is used on other pages or there are multiple instances.

As the name suggests, simpleIoc is very simplistic and does not provide an automatic way.

Comment: I read somewhere that the Messenger uses WeakReference. Can you point me to any document which could validate that the SimpleIoc in mvvm light is also using weak reference. I would be obliged. Thanks.

Comment: I just double checked and you're right: Instances are kept forever. You have to use the unregister method to remove them. I updates the answer.

Comment: WP8 used to have a function OnRemovedFromJournal which was fired when the page was destroyed. In Wp8.1 no such thing exist. Its difficult to manage when to call UnRegister function. I dont want to unregister it OnNavigatedFrom, as it is fired when I navigate from B->C or when I come back from C->B. any clue about this?

Comment: I think MVVM light's ViewModelLocator will manage VM on other pages. and the same will ensure no multiple instances. Thanks for your help :)